# How to handle multiple checkboxes using React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks

I need to control all checkboxes using hooks in React

Code for parent

```
const Filter = () => {

  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState({
    all: false,
    without: false,
    one: false,
    two: false,
    three: false,
  })

  const handleChange = ({ target : { name, checked } }) => {
    setIsChecked({ 
      ...isChecked, 
      [name]: checked 
    })
  }

  const checkboxes = [
    {
      key: "all",
      name: "all",
      htmlFor: "all",
      label: "Все"
    },
    {
      key: "without",
      name: "without",
      htmlFor: "without",
      label: "Без пересадок"
    },
    {
      key: "one",
      name: "one",
      htmlFor: "one",
      label: "1 пересадка"
    },
    {
      key: "two",
      name: "two",
      htmlFor: "two",
      label: "2 пересадки"
    },
    {
      key: "three",
      name: "three",
      htmlFor: "three",
      label: "3 пересадки"
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div className="content__filter">
      <div className="content__filter__name">
        Количество пересадок
      </div>
      <div className="content__filter__list">
        <ul>
          {checkboxes.map(item => (
            <ListItem 
              key={item.key}
              name={item.name} 
              htmlFor={item.htmlFor} 
              label={item.label}
              checked={isChecked[item.name]}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Filter;
```

Code for children

```
const ListItem = ({ type = "checkbox", name, htmlFor, label, onChange, checked }) => {
  console.log(checked)
  return (
    <li>
      <input type={type} name={name} checked={checked} onChange={onChange}/>
      <label htmlFor={htmlFor}>{label}</label>
    </li>
  )
};

export default ListItem;
```

Checkboxes don't react at all. I mean if I click, nothing happens. I get false property all the time in the children and it can't be switched. Also it doesn't work if I set `isChecked` as an empty object (like in this example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-xzvq5?file=/src/index.js:380-382) What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated

P.s. CSS for checkbox

```
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;

  &:hover {
    background: #F1FCFF;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  input {
    display: none;
  }

  label {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #4A4A4A;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  input + label {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    user-select: none;
  }

  input + label::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    border: 1px solid #9ABBCE;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
  }

  input:checked + label::before {
    border-color: #2196F3;
    background-image: url("../../img/shape.png");
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? it seems to be working.

Comment: @Prateek Thapa, checkbox doesn't switch when I click

Comment: you mean the checkboxes are not `checked` when clicked?

Comment: @Prateek Thapa, yes

Comment: Create a sandbox just like that example?

Comment: @Prateek Thapa, it's strange

Comment: @Prateek Thapa, hm, I checked in a sandbox, it works, but doesn't work on my localhost

Comment: It's not strange. It means something is wrong in your localhost. Your CSS maybe messing it up. Are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: @Prateek Thapa, ye, I made a custom checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is solved. It's all about input attributes. I was passing `htmlFor` property into ListItem for `item.name`, but not for id. So I needed to create an id property in my `checkboxes` array and pass `htmlFor` property like this `htmlFor={item.id}`

Don't forget to pass `id` property to ListItem as well like `id={item.id}`